# RichText has different text size on some devices

Tags: flutter, text

I'm using `RichText` in my app but when I use it on some Android phones the text is bigger than when I use a `Text` with the same style.

How can I ensure that also `RichText` uses the same text size as `Text`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer.
This error happens on devices with a different font size or display size. So the user has changed the text scaling for the whole OS (in my case to smaller). The framework - I guess Android - doesn't consider that for `RichText`.
You have to manually apply the scale factor:

```dart
RichText(
    textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
    text: TextSpan(''),
)
```

UPDATE: `textScaleFactor` has been deprecated and you should now use `textScaler`. I think the issue is therefore solved on the framework side.